# performance of `std::string` really bad compared to C-string (`malloc` + `memcpy`)

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2012, stl

I just stumbled upon very bad performance of `std::string`. I expected that a new `std::string` creation from some external data (e.g. `std::string(X.c_str())`) would be roughly equivalent to a `data = malloc(X.size())` + `strcpy(data, X.c_str())`, with some minor constant overhead.

Some example performance code:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

static const char SampleString[] =
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
    "Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. Hello world. "
;

static size_t N = 1000000;

// mostly for avoiding compiler optimization
void readStr(const char* _s) {
    volatile const char* s = _s;
    while(*s) ++s;
}

void cppStringLoop1() {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::string tmp(SampleString);
        readStr(&tmp[0]);
    }
}

void cppStringLoop2() {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        std::string tmp(SampleString, SampleString + sizeof(SampleString));
        readStr(&tmp[0]);
    }
}

void cStringLoop() {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        char* tmp = (char*) malloc(sizeof(SampleString));
        memcpy(tmp, SampleString, sizeof(SampleString));
        readStr(tmp);
        free(tmp);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    assert(argc >= 2);
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-c") == 0) cStringLoop();
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-c++1") == 0) cppStringLoop1();
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-c++2") == 0) cppStringLoop2();
    else assert(false);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems that with MSVC in Release mode, my initial assumption is correct. (Release mode = MSVC Release Runtime lib + optimizations.)

However, in Debug mode (MSVC Debug Runtime lib + no optimizations), it looks like this assumption is wrong. The overhead is not so minor (about 175%).

Maybe it is also the MSVC 2012 `std::string` implementation. Here some numbers:

```
$ time ./TestStringPerf.exe -c

real    0m6.879s
user    0m0.015s
sys     0m0.015s

$ time ./TestStringPerf.exe -c++1

real    0m10.524s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ./TestStringPerf.exe -c++2

real    0m10.106s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.015s
```

Or maybe this is just the overhead to expect.

Comment: You keep using `sizeof(SampleString)`. `SampleString` is a pointer. Your C code is therefore only copying about 4-8 characters.

Comment: When you fix the `sizeof(pointer)` thing, the C variant doesn't copy the string terminator, so you will have undefined behavior in your `readStr` function.

Comment: @Simple That should be an answer.

Comment: Also, according to [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at), an `tmp[x]` operation will return the string terminator only if `x` is equal to `tmp.size()`. It says nothing about having the string terminator otherwise. So using `&tmp[0]` might cause undefined behavior as well. Use [`std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) if you want to get a proper terminated C-style string pointer.

Comment: So let's say initializing the string takes this long.  How about testing real-world *usage* of a std::string v. char array in an actual program?  Initialization and copying isn't the only thing happening to string data within a non-trivial program.  How about concatenation of string data?  What if an application uses small strings, and short-string optimization for std::string would then kick in as opposed to calling malloc() and free() with your C methods?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, my bad for the error. I fixed it and updated my question. It's still too much overhead in Debug mode, but in Release mode, it's now like I would expect it.

Comment: @Albert Debug mode performance is *totally irrelevant.* You don't judge who's the fastest runner by who can remember the most numbers posted along the track.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That sample code is actually a reduced test case from some real-world code, where the impact was much bigger (in some test case: 4secs with C-strings vs 14secs with `std::string`).

Comment: @Angew: No, it's not. In Debug mode, it uses the MSVC Debug Runtime lib and has optimization disabled. Both have a huge impact.

Comment: @Albert Of course. What I meant is, the compiler is not trying to produce fast code in debug mode, it's trying to produce safe (and debuggable) code. You shouldn't *care* about debug mode performance.

Comment: @Albert - Debug mode isn't just optimizations.  If you are compiling a true debug version (where the _DEBUG preprocessor is set), there is a whole lot more going on.  There are iterator checks that are being done and other runtime checking being performed.  So turning optimizations on/off for _DEBUG has very little impact on speed.

Comment: @Albert Are you going to use debug builds for anything other then debugging? Probably not. Then I don't see how debug performance is relevant in the end, you/your clients are going to use release builds in production environment.

Comment: The thing is, the performance difference in my real application is so massive and performance is totally critical there, also in debug mode, that I cannot use `std::string` for that reason (or just never use debug mode). And that looks like a bad situation - better if I could understand why `std::string` is so slow in debug mode and make it perform normal.

Answer (score 8):

You keep using `sizeof(SampleString)`. `SampleString` is a pointer. Your C code and `cppStringLoop2` function are therefore only copying about 4-8 characters.

You need to either:

- change your uses of `sizeof(SampleString)` to `std::strlen(SampleString)`;
- or change `static const char* SampleString` to `static const char SampleString[]` and use `sizeof(SampleString)` in some places and `sizeof(SampleString) - 1` in others (i.e. the `cppStringLoop2` function).

Comment: Worth noting that with those corrections (using an array) timings become really similar, within 1% of each other (I also changed `tmp[0]` to `tmp.data()`/`tmp.c_str()`).

Comment: Yes, my bad, stupid mistake. I fixed it. The numbers are much different now. But the question still stays open, because there is still some overhead now.

Comment: Btw., your answer is now a bit obsolete because it doesn't answer my real question.

Comment: @Albert have you tried `#define`-ing `_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL` as `0`?